# Pytorch: Create an boolean tensor (type: torch.ByteTensor)?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to create a tensor only containing boolean values. 
In Matlab that would be

```
a = false(10,1)
```

Comment: Since version 1.2.0 PyTorch supports boolean [tensors](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.BoolTensor).

Answer (score 36):

Isn't this more economical (albeit longer):

```
a = torch.zeros(10, dtype=torch.bool)
```

or, in older versions,

```
a = torch.zeros(10, dtype=torch.uint8)
```

(Thanks @drevicko for the pointer to bool.)

Comment: There's now a [`torch.bool`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_attributes.html#torch.torch.dtype) type you can (should?) use.

Comment: @drevicko indeed, for instance `torch.where(cond,a,b)` will print a deprecated warning if `cond` is of type `ByteTensor`. You can conveniently use `.type(torch.bool)` to avoid the warning: `cond.type(torch.bool)`.

Answer (score 9):

Already found it:

```
a = torch.zeros(10)
b = a.type(torch.ByteTensor)
```

Comment: A shorter version of this: `torch.zeros(10).byte()`.

Comment: Pytorch now has `torch.bool`. Please use that instead of `torch.ByteTensor`.

Comment: obsolete answer.  how can one get obsolete answers unaccepted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `torch.full` to create a tensor with any arbitrary value, including booleans:

```py
torch.full((20, 15), True)
```

```py
torch.full((20, 15), False)
```

Or, you can use `torch.ones` or `torch.zeros` by specifying the `torch.bool` data type:

```py
torch.ones((20, 15), dtype=torch.bool) # True
```

```py
torch.zeros((20, 15), dtype=torch.bool) # False
```